# Laravel 7: Unable to Run Dev on Fresh Install

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

I am currently performing these terminal commands:

1. composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0
2. composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
3. php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
4. npm install && npm run dev

This returns the following error

```
sh: mix: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jonahmar/.npm/_logs/2021-02-23T15_46_54_252Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jonahmar/.npm/_logs/2021-02-23T15_46_54_277Z-debug.log
```

I am unable to fix or identify the issue, I have performed the following in an attempt to fix the issue:

1. npm rebuild node-sass
2. npm install --global cross-env
3. npm cache clean --force
4. npm install laravel-mix --save-dev

To no avail, I am also getting a warning prior to running this command:

```
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/jonahmar/nodevenv/onyx.website.io/12/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
```

The current web-server is Litespeed Enterprise, with the latest version of composer, and node.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json file content

Comment: Edited to include!

Comment: Try using `"laravel-mix": "^5.0.1"` and change your scripts like in Laravel 7.x [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3923e7f7c40368a5e78c1a33610191be8ad91e3b/package.json#L3)

Comment: I should also mention that I had problems with laravel-mix and node 14/15, so lowering the node version to 12, things got working again